# JSON file recursive iterating is returning 'undefined' and the found values

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

I'm trying to iterate through a json file to build a folder and file structure from a template. However when I specify a specific key to log it logs both the keys, AND the values I want. Is there any way to fix this issue? Why is it even doing this?

```js
function scan(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    for (var k in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        scan(obj[k]);
        var val = obj[k];
        console.log(val.dir + '/' + val.file+ '.'+val.ext + '\n');
      }
    }
  }
}
json = [
    {
      "dir": ".github",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "file": "ISSUE_TEMPLATE",
          "ext": "md",
          "data": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir": ".vscode",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "file": "extensions",
          "ext": "json"
        },
        {
          "file": "settings",
          "ext": "json"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir": "app",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "dir": "src",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "dir": "crash",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "dir": "styles",
                  "nodes": [
                    {
                      "file": "crash",
                      "ext": "scss"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "file": "index",
                  "ext": "tsx"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir": "lib"
            },
            {
              "dir": "main-process",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "dir": "menu",
                  "nodes": [
                    {
                      "file": "index",
                      "ext": "ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "file": "main",
                  "ext": "ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir": "models"
            },
            {
              "dir": "shared-process",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "file": "index",
                  "ext": "ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir": "ui",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "file": "index",
                  "ext": "tsx"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir": "static",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "dir": "common"
            },
            {
              "dir": "logos"
            },
            {
              "file": "error",
              "ext": "html",
              "data": true
            },
            {
              "file": "index",
              "ext": "html",
              "data": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir": "styles",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "dir": "mixins"
            },
            {
              "dir": "ui",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "file": "_app-menu-bar",
                  "ext": "scss"
                },
                {
                  "file": "_focus",
                  "ext": "scss"
                },
                {
                  "file": "_title-bar",
                  "ext": "scss"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "file": "_globals",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "_mixins",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "_type",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "_ui",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "_variables",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "_vendor",
              "ext": "scss"
            },
            {
              "file": "appname",
              "ext": "scss"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir": "test"
        },
        {
          "file": "package",
          "ext": "json",
          "data": true
        },
        {
          "file": "webpack.common",
          "ext": "js"
        },
        {
          "file": "webpack.development",
          "ext": "js"
        },
        {
          "file": "webpack.production",
          "ext": "js"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir": "docs",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "dir": "contributing",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "file": "setup",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "styleguide",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "tooling",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "troubleshooting",
              "ext": "md"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir": "process",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "file": "issue-triage",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "releasing-updates",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "reviews",
              "ext": "md"
            },
            {
              "file": "roadmap",
              "ext": "md"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir": "technical"
        },
        {
          "file": "installation",
          "ext": "md"
        },
        {
          "file": "README",
          "ext": "md"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir": "script",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "file": "build"
        },
        {
          "file": "debug"
        },
        {
          "file": "dist-info",
          "ext": "js"
        },
        {
          "file": "package"
        },
        {
          "file": "publish"
        },
        {
          "file": "run",
          "ext": "js"
        },
        {
          "file": "start"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": ".gitmodules"
    },
    {
      "file": ".travis",
      "ext": "yml"
    },
    {
      "file": "appveyor",
      "ext": "yml"
    } 
  ]

scan(json)
```

Comment: One thing to consider is that an array is also an object, so `[] instanceof Object` returns true.

Also consider that using for-in on an array will make the iterator variable (k in this case) go from 0, 1, .... Array.length - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the parent directory in your recursive function otherwise the parent dir will always be null. Also you should pass only your `nodes` array to the next call rather than the whole subdocument :

```js
function scan(parent, obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k]) {
      if (obj[k].nodes && obj[k].dir) {
        scan(parent + '/' + obj[k].dir, obj[k].nodes);
      }
      if (obj[k].file && obj[k].ext) {
        console.log(parent + '/' +
          obj[k].file + '.' +
          obj[k].ext + '\n');
      }
    }
  }
}
json = [{
    "dir": ".github",
    "nodes": [{
      "file": "ISSUE_TEMPLATE",
      "ext": "md",
      "data": true
    }]
  },
  {
    "dir": ".vscode",
    "nodes": [{
        "file": "extensions",
        "ext": "json"
      },
      {
        "file": "settings",
        "ext": "json"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dir": "app",
    "nodes": [{
        "dir": "src",
        "nodes": [{
            "dir": "crash",
            "nodes": [{
                "dir": "styles",
                "nodes": [{
                  "file": "crash",
                  "ext": "scss"
                }]
              },
              {
                "file": "index",
                "ext": "tsx"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dir": "lib"
          },
          {
            "dir": "main-process",
            "nodes": [{
                "dir": "menu",
                "nodes": [{
                  "file": "index",
                  "ext": "ts"
                }]
              },
              {
                "file": "main",
                "ext": "ts"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dir": "models"
          },
          {
            "dir": "shared-process",
            "nodes": [{
              "file": "index",
              "ext": "ts"
            }]
          },
          {
            "dir": "ui",
            "nodes": [{
              "file": "index",
              "ext": "tsx"
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dir": "static",
        "nodes": [{
            "dir": "common"
          },
          {
            "dir": "logos"
          },
          {
            "file": "error",
            "ext": "html",
            "data": true
          },
          {
            "file": "index",
            "ext": "html",
            "data": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dir": "styles",
        "nodes": [{
            "dir": "mixins"
          },
          {
            "dir": "ui",
            "nodes": [{
                "file": "_app-menu-bar",
                "ext": "scss"
              },
              {
                "file": "_focus",
                "ext": "scss"
              },
              {
                "file": "_title-bar",
                "ext": "scss"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "file": "_globals",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "_mixins",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "_type",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "_ui",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "_variables",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "_vendor",
            "ext": "scss"
          },
          {
            "file": "appname",
            "ext": "scss"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dir": "test"
      },
      {
        "file": "package",
        "ext": "json",
        "data": true
      },
      {
        "file": "webpack.common",
        "ext": "js"
      },
      {
        "file": "webpack.development",
        "ext": "js"
      },
      {
        "file": "webpack.production",
        "ext": "js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dir": "docs",
    "nodes": [{
        "dir": "contributing",
        "nodes": [{
            "file": "setup",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "styleguide",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "tooling",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "troubleshooting",
            "ext": "md"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dir": "process",
        "nodes": [{
            "file": "issue-triage",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "releasing-updates",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "reviews",
            "ext": "md"
          },
          {
            "file": "roadmap",
            "ext": "md"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dir": "technical"
      },
      {
        "file": "installation",
        "ext": "md"
      },
      {
        "file": "README",
        "ext": "md"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dir": "script",
    "nodes": [{
        "file": "build"
      },
      {
        "file": "debug"
      },
      {
        "file": "dist-info",
        "ext": "js"
      },
      {
        "file": "package"
      },
      {
        "file": "publish"
      },
      {
        "file": "run",
        "ext": "js"
      },
      {
        "file": "start"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": ".gitmodules"
  },
  {
    "file": ".travis",
    "ext": "yml"
  },
  {
    "file": "appveyor",
    "ext": "yml"
  }
]

scan('', json)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, why does taking out the parent variable entirely break the function?

Comment: You have to give the parent from each upper node in order to successively concatenate it  (`parent + '/' + obj[k].dir`) to have the correct full path